# How to get json in javascript or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have json data

[image]

how can i get this data using javascript

thanks :)

this is my code

```
 var getJsonData = function(uri,callback){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      url: uri,
      jsonpCallback: 'response',
          contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(json){
        console.log(json);
        callback(json);
      }
    });
  }
```

```
  var uri = pbxApi+"/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid="+circle;
getJsonData(uri, function(res){

  }
```

Comment: Have you tried `JSON.parse(json)`?

Comment: What you have is not a jsonp response...

Comment: hello @ArunPJohny i still got this error `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://192.168.236.33/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid=0090000007. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://192.168.236.14' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.`

Comment: that is because you are dealing with different domain(same origin policy).... so either you need to enable CORS on the json service(supported on modern browsers) or enable jsonp

Comment: ok thanks @ArunPJohny. i will search how to use jsonp

Comment: when you sent a jsonp response the response format should be `jsonpcallbackname(<response>)` like `jsonpcallback({"d":4})`

Comment: thanks @ArunPJohny :)

Comment: what you are getting at `console.log(json)` ??

Answer (score 0):

```
var uri = pbxApi+"/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid="+circle;
getJsonData(uri, function(res){
   var data = JSON.parse(res);
   for(var objectIndex=0; objectIndex < data.length; objectIndex++){
     var tempObject = data[objectIndex];
     var id = tempObject.id;
     var uid = tempObject.uid;
     ....
     var updated_at = tempObject.updated_at;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need use jsonp to get json data,

```
var getJsonData = function(uri,callback){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: uri,
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(json){
        console.log(json);
        callback(json);
      }
    });
  }

 var uri=pbxApi+"/confbridge_participants/conference_participants.json?cid="+circle;
getJsonData(uri, function(res){
console.log(res
  }
```